# Running Entity Framework migrations from installer custom action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-installer, custom-action, entity-framework-migrations

There is a need in the project I am working on to get the database created and updated via the installer we have.

The project is an MVC website so currently the database is configured to be created/updated when Application_Start is hit.

Initializer is set up as following:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext,Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Within the Configuration:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

I would ideally like to simply set the initialiser and run it straight from a C# custom action.  I have been trying something like below, but so far have had no luck.

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult DBSetup(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Migrations.Configuration>());

            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(true);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            session.Log("Error setting up DB: " + err.InnerException);
            session.Log("", err.Message);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

The exception caught does not seem to contain any information, so debugging is proving difficult..

Just wondering if anyone else has tried this, or tried something similar and got something working.

Comment: I understand exactly what you are trying to do (including the MSI/DTF portitions) but I've never tried this.  Brave new territory where the application is written first and responsible for executing the schema migration without putting SQL scripts in the installer to execute.  Not sure how I feel about all this but it appears to be the future and something I'm sure I'll be working on in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would package the entity framework `migrate.exe` with your installer then run the migration command pointing it at the Dll with the migrations.

`Migrate.exe YourApplication.dll /startupConfigurationFile=”..\web.config”`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) for a full list of commands

Comment: this looks promising.  Will this mean having to set the initialiser in the web.config?

Comment: Possibly, I would set your database initializer to null in your web projects and handle all the migrations with the migrate.exe.  I found that running it from the web project was too unpredictable.  I believe that the web.config is needed so it can get the connection strings to the database.